# Align equivalent environment in lncs

Tags: math-mode, equations, lncs

Is there an equivalent `align` environment in `lncs` that has support for multiline equations? I have such an equation that I want to include in my text, and naively injecting `\\` separators into an equation environment doesn't do the trick. For reference, here is the code:

```
\begin{equation}
c(\beta, \Sigma, \Pi, \Lambda, T) = C_t(Tr(\beta T)^{-1}) + \\
C_t(\mathbf{A} \times Tr(\beta, T)) + C_t((\mathbf{A} \times Tr(\beta, T))^{-1}) + \\
C_t(Tr(\beta, T)) + 2 \times (C_i(\beta, \Sigma, \Pi, \Lambda) + C(\mathbf{A}) + HW(c))
\end{equation}
```

Comment: why can you not use `\usepackage{amsmath}` and then use `align` ?

Comment: Do the equation elements need to be numbered? If not, a regular `array` will do the trick.

Comment: @David: Can't use amsmath AFAIK. The code doesn't seem to compile if I include amsmath because a lot of the macros/commands in the lncs class conflict. Or at least that's what appears to be happening...

Answer (score 6):

I cannot find a class or package named `lncs`, did you mean `llncs.cls`?

I can find only one inconsistency between `llncs.cls` and `amsmath.sty`: When `amsmath` tries to redefine math accents, it complains that it cannot redefine `\vec`. This is only a warning and can be safely ignored if you don't use `\vec` or are satisfied with the `llncs` definition of `\vec`.

You can avoid even that warning if you change the loading order:

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\documentclass{llncs}
```

You will then get the `llncs` definition.

If neither of these works for you, perhaps you have a different version of `llncs`. In that case you should supply a link to the version you use. Mine gives its date and version as 2013/09/27 v2.18.